i cant go to my html file in my springboot web app?
when I click with the mouse on the return value I see this message "cannot find declaration to go to"
the controller and project files
when I go to my controller mapping
I try to change file name with the path but I have the same problem
   application.properties is 
`server.port=9090
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springbootdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres@123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.
PostgreSQLDialect`


Don't add code as images or worse links to images. Include the code in the question.

Can you add application.properties? Normally you would have a specific root address instead of directly localhost:x/html

@kenneth done i add application.properties
